# splice in javascript(vue) not working as expected after adding class dynamically

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, animate.css, array-splice

I'm trying to delete an element from an array using array splice method.
I'm also using animate.css and I dynamically add the class 'fadeOutDown' before deleting the element. Then I'm using a timeout function to wait for the animation to complete and remove the element from the array using index.

When I click the delete button the index of the element performs the animation but additionally the very next index is also removed from the DOM but not from the array.

Below the html and js-function for removing the element:

```
<ul class="list-group todos mx-auto text-light">
  <li v-for="(todo , i) in filterTodo" :key="i" 
   class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center 
   animated slideInUp slow">
   <span>{{ todo }}</span>
   <i @click="removeTodo(i , $event)" class="fa fa-trash-o delete">x</i>
  </li>
</ul>
```

```
removeTodo(id, e) {
  e.target.parentElement.classList.remove("slideInUp");
  e.target.parentElement.classList.add("fadeOutDown");
  setTimeout(() => {
    this.todos.splice(id, 1);
  }, 1000);
}
```

Comment: Please split your sentence into multiple sentences. It's hard to follow now.

Comment: You can always use `animate` component for animations to make sure dom is working properly

Comment: Don't use `splice`, replace the whole array with `filter` (and don't `setTimeout`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that using `index` as `key`.

```
<li
  v-for="(todo , i) in filterTodo"
  :key="i" // this will make that bug.
...
```

You should not use `index` as `key` especially when array can be *updated*.

Instead of using `index` as key, it is better to use unique *string* or *index* in each filterTodo item.

**If todo is unique**, you can use that as key directly like below:

```
<li
  v-for="(todo , i) in filterTodo"
  :key="todo"
...
```

Comment: I have no idea that the key is causing the problem... this was my first query here and thanks a lot for replying and your time...